# Why can I not see a mutual friend on one facebook users profile, but I can on another?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, friend-list, facebook-friends

Me and my bf have about 16 mutual friends. I am aware he has his account settings to hide his friends list. Now, there are a few users that I know whom are not on my friends list, but they are on my bfs friend list, but yet when visiting that other users profile, my bf is not listed under mutual friends. However, there will be a different user that is friends with my bf and not me, and when visiting their fb profile, my bf shows as a mutual friend. How does this work? All other users facebook friends lists are visible to public in both circumstances.